# Why is my database not showing up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-administration

Actually in the sql server management studio when I click the database,nothing comes up(+ sign beside the database name is not listing any items) and none of the logins are getting connected.nothing is logged in the error log(except that the login cannot connect to the database).After sometime,automatically the database comes up without doing anything(that is the + sign comes up and all the listing in the management stidio comes up.plz suggest me what will be the reason for this

Comment: I would suggest at looking at the SQL Server service, and seeing if its running when you are trying to connect, and pull up dbs, if its not then you need to see why its stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the SSMS windows by pressing F5. Put focus on "Databases" in the Object Explorer before refresh.

/niels